# Combine objects in js and keep keys

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects.

```
const filters = {  name: "NAME" };
const pages = { sort: "SORT" };
```

need to combine them, but the result should be like

```
{ 
   filters: {  name: "NAME" }
   pages:  {sort: "SORT"}
}
```

with concat or spread operator I am getting

```
{
   name: "NAME",
   sort: "SORT"
}
```

How to combine them and keep keys (filters, pages)?

Comment: How are the objects defined? `filters: {  name: "NAME" }` isn't a full variable definition, can you show what you're currently doing with spread?

Comment: tThey aredefined like const filters = {name: "Name"}. And I am using spread like  let result = {}
result = {...filters,...pages}

Comment: `result = {filters: filters, pages: pages}`

Comment: then you want `{filters, pages}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap the variables `filters` & `pages` inside `{}` like:

```js
const filters = {  name: "NAME" }
const pages = { sort: "SORT" }

let result = { ...{filters}, ...{pages} }
console.log(result)
```

Please notice that inside `result` we are actually creating a new object with key as `filters` but as the key and value of the new object are same, so we can use object short-hand syntax here like:

```js
const filters = {  name: "NAME" }

const obj1 = { filters: filters }
console.log( obj1 )

const obj2 = { filters }
console.log( obj2 )
```

You can see in the above demo result of `obj1` & `obj2` is exactly same. Thus we can use:

```
{ ...{filters}, ...{pages} }
```

instead of doing:

```
{ ...{ filters: filters }, ...{ pages: pages } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't see what you mean, work like a charm:

```js
const a = { filters: {  name: "NAME" }};
const b = {pages:  {sort: "SORT"}};
const x = {...a,...b}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Yeap, the problem was how to define objects. 
const a = { filters: {  name: "NAME" }}; That's what I need
Thanks a lot